# Finding all points to a surface at which the tangent plane is parallel to the $xy$-plane.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

The question: Find all points on the surface $z=x^4+y^3-3y$ at which the tangent plane is parallel to the $xy$-plane.

I have determined that the gradient of the surface is $(4x^3,3y^2-3,-z)$ and the gradient for $xy$-plane is given as $(0,0,1)$.

I am unsure of how to proceed with the information I have, any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

The vector 
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{n}&=\langle 4x_0^3,3(y_0^2-1),-1\rangle
\end{align*}
Is normal to the tangent plane to the surface at $(x_0,y_0,f(x_0,y_0))$, where $$f(x,y)=x^4+y^3-3y$$
If that plane is parallel to the $xy$-plane then $\mathbf{n}$ is parallel to the $z$-axis, so
$$4x_0^3=0\qquad \text{and}\qquad 3(y_0^2-1)=0$$
So $x_0=0$, and $y_0=\pm 1$.